# Can physical drives configured for an HP Proliant DL 380 Gen 9 server be used to boot another server of the same model?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

We are having great difficulty getting physical hard drives that were configured for our server to work in another server of the same model (HP Proliant DL 380 Gen 9).

One would think that I could configure in Smart Storage Administrator the same logical drive arrangement on the new server and boot from the backup hard drives, no?

Each time we tried this, the BIOS failed to recognize any bootable media even though HP Smart Storage Administrator was able to configure the logical devices.

We were very careful to set the drives bootable, but they never show up in the BIOS.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: How many disks? What RAID level were the drives configured in? What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: 1 RAID 0 SSD 120 GB is the only bootable drive with CentOS 6.5. 4 1 TB HDD RAID 5 not part of the OS.  No error messages.  BIOS does not see any bootable drive and tries to boot from the CD ROM after failing to boot from HDD C: or whatever